# Angular and RadialGradient at the same time

Tags: swift, swiftui, cagradientlayer, radial-gradients

I've been trying to create a color wheel with HSB colors like this:

```
var gradient: Gradient {
    return Gradient(stops: stride(from: 0, to: 1, by: 0.01).map { value in
        let color = Color(hue: value, saturation: 1, brightness: 1)
        return Gradient.Stop(color: color, location: CGFloat(value))
    })
}

 Circle()
 .fill(AngularGradient(gradient: gradient, center: .center))
 .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
```

Currently I have a fixed saturation value, as this would need a `RadialGradient` with the colors white (saturation = 0) and the calculated color (saturation = 1). But in SwiftUI you can only fill a `Shape` once so I'm wondering if there is a clean way on how to fill a circle with `AngularGradient` and `RadialGradient` at the same time.

Comment: sorry to say that, it is not possible with SwiftUI at this moment. When ShapeStyle protocol will have a public API, it could change. You have to request Apple ...

Comment: maybe you could play with .blendMode , see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to play with .blendMode(...)

I am not an expert on colors so it is just an idea ..

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var gradient0: Gradient {
        return Gradient(stops: stride(from: 0, to: 1, by: 0.05).map { value in
            let color = Color(hue: value, saturation: 1, brightness: 1)
            return Gradient.Stop(color: color, location: CGFloat(value))
        })
    }
    var gradient1: Gradient {
        return Gradient(stops: stride(from: 0, to: 1, by: 0.05).map { value in
            let color = Color(.displayP3, white: value, opacity: 1)
            return Gradient.Stop(color: color, location: CGFloat(value))
        })
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
            ZStack {

                Circle().fill(RadialGradient(gradient: gradient1, center: .center, startRadius: 0, endRadius: 200))

                Circle().fill(AngularGradient(gradient: gradient0, center: .center))
                    .blendMode(.multiply)

            }
            .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

with the result

[image]